# calling resource menu into other activity

Tags: android

Please help me how can i call a menu resource in other activity . 
Here is code of main activity

```
public class ControlMenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:     
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
            break;
            case R.id.services:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
            case R.id.another: 


        }
        return true;
    }
```

here is menu resource

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


         <item android:id="@+id/Quit"
        android:title="Quit"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" />

        <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" />


        <item android:id="@+id/services"
        android:title="Services"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" />


</menu>
```

i can call it in the other activity by writing the main activity code but for that i have rewrite the case statements as well so guide me how can i solve it out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the menu code to a common Activity subclass, then make all your other Activity classes extend that common class instead of just Activity. For a simple menu this should work just fine.